# How to define class for input variable in VS Code

Tags: python

I'm learning python, suppose I have a class and want to use it as a input variable for other defs:

```
class person:
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def set_name(self):
        self.name = name

def dummy(p):
    print(p.get_name())
```

How to tell the IDE know p is an instance of the class person and suggest the defs of the person like Java.
Thanks you.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, the editor which you are using is almost always irrelevant in questions about code like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a type hint. These are classes you can suggest a certain value will be. Consider this

```py
def say_hello(name: str, age: int) -> None:
    message: str = f'Hello, {name}! You are {age} years old'
    print(message)
```

Here, we say a function `say_hello` will take two args: `name`, which should be an instance of the `str` class, and `age`, which should be an instance of  the `int` class. The function should return `None`, and it defines a local variable `message`  which should also be a string.

Notice how each time I said "should". Python is a dynamically-typed language, so none of these will cause an error if their values aren't instances of the specified class. These are just a peak at what the variables should be for the developer.

Comment: this is what i need. just for suggesttion and debug purpose. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use type hints.

```
class Person:
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def set_name(self):
        self.name = name

def dummy(p: Person):
    print(p.get_name())
```

look up type hints on google and you could research them a bit if you wanted to